# List of ExactTarget Sandbox URIs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, rest

Where can I find a complete list of ExactTarget Sandbox URIs? So far I have only Authenticate with REST.

https://auth-test.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken

but the next request fails, because my account is not authorized for PROD.

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail

same when I attempt to retrieve it through endpoint URI

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/endpoints/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the same for your account, but try using only the production server URLs with your sandbox account.  Our "sandbox" account runs on the production server.  Some terminology got crossed somewhere I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really old post, but why not....

It looks like you can use www-test when using the sandbox